# Extract information from page after redirect in taurus

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I have a page `/login`
after successful login we will be redirected to `/files` How do I extract an information from `/files` page? I use Jmeter as executor

```
          - url: '${host}/login'
            method: POST
            label: 'Login'
            headers:
              Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: '1'
              Origin: 'null'
              Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
              Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
            extract-xpath:
              requesttoken:
                xpath: //head/@data-requesttoken
                default: NOT_FOUND
                validate-xml: false
                ignore-whitespace: true
                use-tolerant-parser: true
            body:
              password: pass
              timezone: Europe/Berlin
              timezone_offset: '2'
              user: admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter should [follow the redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) given you provide [`follow-redirects: true` property.](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#HTTP-Requests)

Also you will need to change the XPath Extractor's scope to sub-samples by adding the [next line:](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Extractors)

```
scope: children
```

You can always launch JMeter GUI by running the following command:

```
bzt your-test.yaml -gui
```

and Taurus will convert your YAML scenario into JMeter Test plan which can be easily launched and debugged.

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: More info about sub-samples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768906/what-does-it-mean-extractor-children-scope-in-taurus/62779609#62779609