# What does it mean extractor children scope in Taurus?

Tags: jmeter, taurus

JMeter extractor in taurus have property `scope`(to check sub-samples)

https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Extractors
`scope: children`

Could you explain what does it mean in example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When redirect is happening or if there are [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) JMeter generates so called "sub-samples" for them:

[image]

- if you want to apply your extractor to the main sample only - leave the `scope` empty
- if you want to apply your extractor to children only - set the `scope` to `children`
- if you want to apply your extractor to the main sample and the children - set the `scope` to `all`

The above are just Taurus equivalents of JMeter's [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

From [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759416/extract-information-from-page-after-redirect-in-taurus) the context is to include page(s) after redirect

Main/Sub samples are [JMeter extractors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) concept

> This is for use with samplers that can generate sub-samples, e.g. HTTP Sampler with embedded resources, Mail Reader or samples generated by the Transaction Controller.
>
> - Main sample only - only applies to the main sample
> - Sub-samples only - only applies to the sub-samples
> - Main sample and sub-samples - applies to both.
> - JMeter Variable Name to use - assertion is to be applied to the contents of the named variable

Corresponding values in taurus

> Possible value for targets are:
>
> - all - main sample and sub-samples
> - children - sub-samples
> - variable for search in JMeter variables
>   Default value of scope is empty, it means search in main sample only.